# d3.js использование БД

Tags: java, база-данных, алгоритм, spring, d3.js

Основная проблема в непонимании того, как связать БД(spring data jpa)+d3.js
(реализация основной программы на spring mvc)

Имеются таблицы
БД(profession,subjects)

Причём profession_has_subject,subject_has_subject - непосредственно связывают таблицы profession,subjects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

нужен вызов, который вернёт JSON, необходимый d3 для работы.

Дополнительно, d3 позволяет обрабатывать различные типы файлов и имеет для этого встроенные функции, например d3.csv. Иными словами, если вы будете складывать данные в csv, вы сможете их обрабатывать средствами d3 напрямую.

Однако, следует быть осторожным с этим в некоторых браузерах, - Chrome, например считает это Cross Origin Request и выдаёт ошибку.

Comment: Неужели нельзя обойтись без JSON,учитывая, что я использовала  SPRING DATA JPA для работы с БД??? @Mr. Brightside

Comment: Боюсь, что нет. Либо JSON, либо массив JSON'ов, либо некоторые типы файлов. [Вот ссылка](https://www.dashingd3js.com/data-structures-d3js-accepts), описывающая типы данных, которые можно скормить d3.

Comment: А как в таком случае между объектами сохраниться связь? Если мы просто передадим массив объектов?

Comment: Из полезного, что нашел быстро и, возможно, вам пригодится хотя бы как отправная точка: [документ](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/), описывающий как обращаться к Spring Data по REST'у, получая тем самым JSON.

Comment: @Nadezhda вы говорите о real-time построении? Или вы имеете ввиду, как связанные между собой вещи в БД будут связаны между собой на графике? тут ваш вопрос можно трактовать двояко

Comment: Моя задача заключается в том, чтобы построить граф из связных(дисциплин и профессий) По примеру http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1044242  .Сейчас я разбираюсь с погрузкой данных . И мне непонятно как они связаны в графе.   (С помощью Spring data jpa я связала таблицы между собой)

Comment: В общем случае вам необходим source и target, чтобы знать что с чем соединять. Точно так же строятся станции метро при помощи d3: есть source node (кружок, откуда проводить линию), есть target node (куда проводить линию). Вы это можете сообщать либо в самом JSON'е, либо делать соответствующую обработку уже при получении данных, просто добавляя эти атрибуты-ссылки.

Comment: В примере, который вы скинули используется [этот](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/1044242/readme-flare-imports.json) JSON. Каждый элемент там содержит атрибут imports, который указывает связи между элементами